# How to export point cache from linked group?

Tags: export

I would like to be able to export the cache from a referenced/linked group of objects. My problem is that even if each mesh of the referenced group exist in the outliner (in BlendfileData > Objects), I can not select them. 
In my blend file I have a character with different meshes (head, body, arms, etc) and its rig.